# Variables in css.scss file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

Seems like this should be a simple thing. I'm just trying to use some varialbes in my css.scss file. My understanding is I just define them at the top of the file:

```
$gf-green: #222;
$gf-aqua: #33ccff;
```

I try to use one of them later in the file:

```
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: $gf-aqua;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;

  &:hover {
    color: #33cc33;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

When I render the page it gives:

```
Invalid CSS after " background: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"

.guide-signup-btn {
  background: ;
}

.guidefind-nav-right {
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
```

So it's not filling in the variable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your variables correctly and they work. Looks like the problem is coming from the `.guide-signup-btn` section of your scss, but you're correct in terms of how to set the variables.

[Link to your scss working with the font color on codepen](http://codepen.io/tim-hoff/pen/ZbraqE)

Comment: Yes, it was a syntax error. The value for background was not define. I assumed the problem was with the new variables. Thanks for the debugging help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped.